# Unable to communicate with master with roscore running

Tags: roscore, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to subscribe to a node I launched on a raspberry pi on my laptop. I am able to SSH into the raspberry pi to launch the node (the problem is not that roscore isn't running because it is), but when I open another terminal and run rostopic list, the cursor blinks for a while before I get an "Unable to communicate with master" error. Both of my machines have the same ROS_MASTER_URI, which is http://cameraduckie.local:11311. This hostname is the one that I ssh into from my laptop to launch the first node. I am very confused because the two machines can ping each other but the laptop cannot communicate with master--any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Taylor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274588/unable-to-communicate-with-master-with-roscore-running/) by [tayagrey6](https://answers.ros.org/users/32442/tayagrey6/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds that you didn't configure your ROS_IP variable.

Let's assume that the IP of your master (where the roscore is running - the raspberry pi in your case) is 192.168.1.1, so you will have to run

> export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.1:11311

> export ROS_IP=192.168.1.1

And assume on the slave computer the IP is 192.168.1.2, you will have to run

> export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.1:11311

> export ROS_IP=192.168.1.2

After that you should have ROS connectivity

---

Originally posted by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) with karma: 105 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tayagrey6](https://answers.ros.org/users/32442/tayagrey6/) on 2017-11-01**:
Hi Oded, I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work either--I receive the same error as before. I had this whole configuration working via ethernet before, but then it stopped working when I switched over to wifi--if that helps at all. Thank you for your response!